# Ctrl-o with ignore "No write since last change"

Tags: vim

I can press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> to go to the last jump point. However, if there are any changes in the current document it warns me with:

> E37: No write since last change (add ! to override)

Is there a way to ignore that message and do `ctrl-o` and either (1) discard any changes; or (2) save any changes and do ctrl-o?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Discard any changes --- No.
2. Save any changes --- `set autowrite` or `set autowriteall`
3. Hide buffer but keep it in memory (can ask for saving it later) --- `set hidden`
4. Ask if you want to save a buffer --- `set confirm`

Note: (2), (3) and (4) are global options and change Vim behaviour for many(!) commands.

Answer (score 0):

2) Here is a simple command for your `.vimrc` that will save the file before jumping:

```
noremap <C-O> :update<C-M><C-O>
```

EDIT: Use `:update` instead of `:w` to avoid re-writing the file when it was not previously modified.

1) I looked for the equivalent solution to discard the changes instead of saving them, using `:e!` instead of `:w`, but that modifies the list of jump points in a way that break `<C-O>` completely.